# Azure B2C: "The provided id_token failed signature validation"

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I am creating an identity provider, and have plumbed it into a B2C custom policy.

Discovery happens fine, and the user gets sent to my idp fine. 
However, when I return the user back to B2C, using the `id_token` response type (the only response type I am supporting at the moment) B2C gives me the error in the title. The full error is:

```
error_description=AADB2C90239: The provided id_token failed signature validation. Please provide another token and try again.
```

Everything else I am validating my token against (jwt.io, various node jwt/jwk verification methods) seems to be happy with what I am returning, only B2C isn't.

[Here is an example of my id_token response](https://jwt.ms/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImtpZGR5MTIzIn0.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.P4jfkEKckie0EYn-es2kjOzmdSphmHJ9jk9HLep3OdPSmTYyInYreOnF92IE8qkpNLAlUlyTv-vdsnBEbwwhxexmGi4_SufhDMSYdNfe3rd2Q27qO9mCWWe6nYW3zT62M4FJ_c5fHjksLS85vxbE249lX_PpRrIBIKjmv9t_Is8UoNzuzaB87J8-3cZt4GZuMaixINs4QR547hM049TQdrl6lWrLn_teGFp8o3rDI3ksCSsFDCaqcKbtnJJW2P_FrT1O9YxKphe0RRnnq2qDM75B5udY79P1xHzGf1NJCT-9iXfCvBu5y8yTNLaDXNQO_Y_CZycp6nezYtUCCc6s77-YlhpRYGAg_ZUSFpC6d3LYX5a-IV7YCoCwqn3NjOBoUnulUyfCoyB9SESz3mOHigUvIEh5W3kJgptipAP5iCMoYdygpR18HSpDSSDzQtDBMR7_seDuYvTXjffmn7NPg2HeUD7-ZS0VsVRaTw1-3B7Elifmikn6QSa5N_kjIBN4fa5byh33RAfTpT3XnEPzUAsSp6jaGIZPDCV9-0PjEqs3EaakVwgtwh442v2Otq-7oYozS016nceuAazbpw7kuCSEJdHChaWsx1WWbUQDaTKNriW7lrYnVinEgHHfHeh_mnXtmpBxSORleu53Fmc_VKNzahAFZePdjb-Ol0Oi2nc)

I am just running it on my local machine, hence the issuer being ngrok, but my openid-configuration looks like this:

```
{
"issuer": "https://28b5fe46.ngrok.io",
"authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:3000/authentication/auth",
"jwks_uri": "https://28b5fe46.ngrok.io/.well-known/openid-configuration/keys",
"response_modes_supported": [
    "query"
],
"response_types_supported": [
    "id_token"
],
"scopes_supported": [
    "openid"
],
"subject_types_supported": [
    "public"
],
"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
],
"claims_supported": [
    "sub"
]
}
```

and my keys look like this:

```
{
"keys": [
{
"kid": "kiddy123",
"alg": "RS256",
"kty": "RSA",
"use": "sig",
"n": "ALdnY_dWrQgjaqWuqUFpr-__p62xsWSWGiVH9CEWlxOTGrR8jhfG_C_xxGkkptWrVWwJgpmJ7zOMFXjqc9HqGCitl9Czl-X68Ld2xnZ_HdmikRTv-Witn8V-5QiQhSEGwvA2Xek8OVWKWOZ7Z4L9_SjNar33E8zGGFtz77_pmzJ6_zompGQSkLwAMTU3buI8TUKFIOBLGtc_eFCfgcbHFjJuYYp_200A4Xz2a0lNvvHSZ8PLKmwoRIBbFhkhe0zFd0mwq97SavTUXrltZnq3ghTbc6QzJC4T3_4J1LMTEQIFpaK3jK9VPFrLVESy8Ovz4CdxsfY3_bv2QX2HfPOxJziDIOsoztXUvfPPH-tu5nZ2JpKuE5ftAL3W7LbR5SCe2fHqV8aSsJbyDP2fHKbjy1pBhx_MQ2ty17YJRcqHER0l2GEhRf7AhdewIdv2_LdMIUr1tYuYWLuiZVN682fgYZZGl_TAxhBSyi65uzXbziG4STpENkX8KvBPjkMJc-EfwRcegJzS2kJVd-fnE5fCF2lHuo0hC93piViUhtzo6_1R5AXKk2JKxs_kWRd30E7DE8LZPRw-2hM3zrEQ6X5VL7q-UvHLR6SUKdjHXPYUX2FJAuj8EhQlqhovf26_pwO26wHhBl8mkJo9T8c8MQSVz3y12AJbP99-lo0We5umk4uP",
"e": "AQAB"
}
]
}
```

The B2C journey recorder doesn't give me any extra information, only the aforementioned error.

Does anyone know how I might debug this further?

Here is how I am creating the id_token. You can see near the bottom I am validating the token against the pem that was used to create the jwks.

```js
const { session } = common.getServices(request)
const sessionValues = session.get(request)
const pem = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', '..', '..', 'jwtRS256.key'))

const {
  nonce,
  redirectUri,
  state,
  databucketItems: { sub },
  clientId
} = sessionValues

const jwk = njwk.JWK.fromJSON(JSON.stringify({
  'kid': 'kiddy123',
  'alg': 'RS256',
  'kty': 'RSA',
  'use': 'sig',
  'n': 'ALdnY_dWrQgjaqWuqUFpr-__p62xsWSWGiVH9CEWlxOTGrR8jhfG_C_xxGkkptWrVWwJgpmJ7zOMFXjqc9HqGCitl9Czl-X68Ld2xnZ_HdmikRTv-Witn8V-5QiQhSEGwvA2Xek8OVWKWOZ7Z4L9_SjNar33E8zGGFtz77_pmzJ6_zompGQSkLwAMTU3buI8TUKFIOBLGtc_eFCfgcbHFjJuYYp_200A4Xz2a0lNvvHSZ8PLKmwoRIBbFhkhe0zFd0mwq97SavTUXrltZnq3ghTbc6QzJC4T3_4J1LMTEQIFpaK3jK9VPFrLVESy8Ovz4CdxsfY3_bv2QX2HfPOxJziDIOsoztXUvfPPH-tu5nZ2JpKuE5ftAL3W7LbR5SCe2fHqV8aSsJbyDP2fHKbjy1pBhx_MQ2ty17YJRcqHER0l2GEhRf7AhdewIdv2_LdMIUr1tYuYWLuiZVN682fgYZZGl_TAxhBSyi65uzXbziG4STpENkX8KvBPjkMJc-EfwRcegJzS2kJVd-fnE5fCF2lHuo0hC93piViUhtzo6_1R5AXKk2JKxs_kWRd30E7DE8LZPRw-2hM3zrEQ6X5VL7q-UvHLR6SUKdjHXPYUX2FJAuj8EhQlqhovf26_pwO26wHhBl8mkJo9T8c8MQSVz3y12AJbP99-lo0We5umk4uP',
  'e': 'AQAB'
}))

const time = new Date().getTime()

const jwt = njwt.create({
  iss: 'https://28b5fe46.ngrok.io',
  name: 'Cheese man',
  aud: clientId,
  nonce,
  redirectUri,
  state,
  sub
}, pem, jwk.alg)

jwt.setHeader('kid', 'kiddy123')
jwt.setExpiration(time + (12 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
jwt.setNotBefore(time - (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000))

const compacted = jwt.compact()

const returnUrl = `${sessionValues.redirectUri}?${qs.stringify({
  id_token: compacted,
  state
})}`

/** Just for verifying the id_token**/
const verifier = njwt.createVerifier().withKeyResolver((kid, next) => {
  return pem.toString()
})

const parsedJwt = verifier.verify(compacted)
console.log(parsedJwt) // This prints the token correctly - meaning it is valid

return h.redirect(returnUrl)
```

Comment: Could you show the process you got the token?

Comment: Do you mean how I'm creating the token? B2C is the one retrieving the token. I'll add how I'm creating the token.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error after tweaking some settings and can't get rid of it after reverting all my changes. Did you find a solution @Chrift?

Comment: @Chrift We are experiencing the same exact issue, I wish there was a solution posted, what did you do to solve the issue?

Comment: @softbear were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @softbear and Chase W. I was not able to find a solution and moved onto something. I may be revisiting this in the coming months so will update this post if I overcome this.